# Using Windows SEH and GCC label-as-value to jump to local error handler

Tags: c, windows, gcc, seh

I need to unit test some code where the failure cases raise an exception. In a nutshell, I need to handle the exception by either unwinding a stack frame or making a local jump over the error. Using MSVC is not an option.

The [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for AddVectoredExceptionHandler indicates that I can modify eip and then return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION to perform a local jump. The obvious question is what to what address to jump. GCC's [Label as Value](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) feature seems like it should be just the thing.

The example below works if there is a single return from the erroring function. However, if a second return statement is added, the offset of the jump is suspiciously small and the jump fails. Why?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

static bool handler_called;
static DWORD handler_eip;

static LONG WINAPI local_handler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ExceptionInfo) {
   handler_called = true;
   PCONTEXT Context = ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord;
   Context->Eip = handler_eip;
   return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

static void badcall(void) {
   handler_called = false;
   handler_eip = &&fail;

   int value = 100;
   int zero = 0;
   value = value/0;
   printf("not handled.\n");
   assert(false);
   //return; // Uncomment this to break the handler

   fail:
   printf("error handled.\n");
   return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   void* old_handler = SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(&local_handler);
   badcall();
   SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(old_handler);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the disassembly of this code? Noticing anything strange in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC's dead code elimination seems to be the culprit -- nothing to do with SEH. When the bottom block of the function is not reachable, those statements are eliminated. GCC then arbitrarily creates a label at the location where we took the address.

Since we're manipulating program flow directly, the rules of C tell us that we're not allowed to complain when the compiler does something wacky like this.

Here is a more minimal example:

```
static void* handler_eip;
static void badcall(void) {
   handler_eip = &&fail;

   int value = 100/0;
   printf("not handled.\n");
   //goto fail;
   return;

   fail:
   printf("error handled.\n");
   return;
}
```

Note the location of L2 with the goto in place:

```
_badcall:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $56, %esp
    movl    $L2, _handler_eip
    movl    $100, %eax
    movl    $0, -28(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $31, %edx
    idivl    -28(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    nop
L2:
    movl    $LC1, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    nop
    leave
    ret
```

And without:

```
_badcall:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $56, %esp
L2:
    movl    $L2, _handler_eip
    movl    $100, %eax
    movl    $0, -28(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $31, %edx
    idivl    -28(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    nop
    leave
    ret
```